# question about iterators and pointers to data structures in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator

i am trying to do some data structures assignments in c++ and i am kinda stuck in here:

The function below is supposed to take the data from data and put all the odd numbers in the result vector.

When i am trying to run the piece of code with some unit tests i get an exception(probably bad memory access?).

Any ideas what am i doing bad? I am guessing that i might have a problem with my iterator on how to declare it.

Is there a function that i can use from stl to make it simpler?

```
template<typename T>static int odds(const std::vector<T> &data, std::vector<T> *result){

if (data.empty()) return 0;

auto it=result->begin();

std::copy_if(std::begin(data),std::end(data),it++,isOdd<T>);

return result->size();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code looks fine.  Please post of [mre] of the test that fails.

Comment: Ideally `result` should be passed by reference instead of pointer so it can't be null as your function depends on that.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica thanks for your response, since i cannot put code in here i can provide you with a screenshot to the unit test https://prnt.sc/q9yi16

Comment: Does the `result` vector have enough memory to store the odd numbers from the `data` vector? If not, then you have a memory leak. Where do you call `push_back()` or `emplace_back()`

Comment: Yer... so from your screenshot, the vector is empty. And I can't see you allocating memory anywhere. Therefore, it makes sense to give you a segfault. You can use `std::back_inserter` inside the `std::copy_if` and your problem is solved.

Comment: @ElementahOfficial You can [edit] your question and copy-paste the code into it.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos It is not a memory leak and OP does not need to allocate memory (manually). He is accessing out-of-bounds though and that is fixed by using `back_inserter` or resizing in some other way, as you say.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica `it++` as argument to `copy_if` is not likely to be fine.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos thanks for your response, it is now solved.

Comment: @walnut: OP could allocate memory beforehand when he declares the result vector by taking the size of the original vector. `std::back_inserter` will do that too for every element. But it can become slower. And if you know the size of the original vector, then why not just create a similar sized result vector. But you're right, it's a segmentation fault not a memory leak - got confused as was in a hurry.